# How do I compare objects that are arrays when I don't know what the array type is?

Tags: c#

I'm writing some unit tests. I have several data rows:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataRow(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 })]
[DataRow(new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 })]
[DataRow(new string[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" })]
```

And the test method is essentially:

```
public void TestOfArrayTypes(object expected) {
  var actual = fn(expected);

  Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

My problem is the comparison. Both variables are `object`. I know they're both going to be arrays. The assertion fails because while they are both arrays, even of the same type and same elements, they aren't the same array reference.

That's expected, just how do I make an assertion here work that validates they are the same type, length, and elements?

I've also tried:

```
Assert.IsTrue(expected.Equals(actual));
```

And unfortunately, `SequenceEqual` isn't available on `object`, but I don't know how to cast `object` to some generic array type.

Comment: "Both variables are object. I know they're both going to be arrays." - Can you not use some form of collection then, instead of object?

Comment: Do these *need* to be of type `object`?  Why can't the code use a more specific type, or generics?

Comment: @shree.pat18 @David, `fn` represents an interface that accepts `object` and returns `object`. Internally, it only handles primitive types and their array types, it otherwise throws an exception. I cannot change the interface. I'm asking because we are not principally a C# developers and I'm basically the only one on my team learning the type system as I go, the rest are writing code like it's all just like C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using MsTest, then you can use `CollectionAssert` and cast to `ICollection`:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataRow(new [] { 1, 2, 3 },new [] { 1, 2, 3 })]
[DataRow(new [] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 }, new [] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 })]
[DataRow(new [] { "foo", "bar", "baz" }, new object[] {new [] { "foo", "bar", "baz" }})]
public void TestMethod2(object array, object array2)
{
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(array as ICollection, array2 as ICollection);
}
```

Or change the test method parameter type to `ICollection`.

Comment: `ICollection` expects a type argument. You know, for being a reflective language and espouses so much about covariance, you'd think `ICollection<object>` would have been suitable... So what now?

Comment: @MatthewReddington _"ICollection expects a type argument"_ - no, it does not, there is a non-generic version of the interface. The code in answer was compiled and run as unit test.

Comment: @MatthewReddington you need [`ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection?view=net-7.0) from `System.Collections`, add appropriate using.